# How can i load(show) a part of big image in flutter's widget?

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I wanna load(show) a part of big image in flutter's widget,by use low memory as i can.
And i known a  BitmapRegionDecoder class can do this at android platform, is this similar Class/Method at Flutter ?

My last plan is decode at android, and transport result's data to flutter by Channel for show.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the Widget `InteractiveViewer()`. You can see a [Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zrn7V3bMJvg).

Comment: thanks for you reply,but i dont think this widget will save memory at case of show big image. For example， there is a image (about 40m memory) and i just wanna show quater of it, so how can i just use less than 40mb memory to show it.